# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un Background a una página web?, no me cargan los estilos CSS

Tags: javascript, css, netbeans

Estoy usando NetBeans y Bootstrap.

Como ven todo está gris y no se aplican los estilos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí coloqué los estilos, pero no los carga como ya intenté Ctrl + F5:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
body {
    background-image:   url('../img/ep_naturalblack.png') !important;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-color: #07121e !important;
}
```

```html
   

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
            <title>Easter Eggs</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
        <body>   
            <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Este botón despliega la barra de navegación</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Easter Eggs</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Entradas</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Favoritos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Autores</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <u1 class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Iniciar sesion</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Registro</a></li>
                        </u1>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </nav>
            
            <div class="container">
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="container">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>Easter Eggs</h1>
                    <p>
                        Web dedicada a descubrir y compartir los Easter Eggs de los Videojuegos
                    </p>
                </div>        
            </div>
    
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Busqueda
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Que buscas?">
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="form-control">Buscar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" aria-hidden="true"></span> Filtro
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> Archivo
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ultimas entradas
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>Todavia no hay entradas que mostrar</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: No podemos ayudarte si no aportas el código que estás utilizando, por favor revisa este enlace sobre cómo preguntar correctamente en este sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   También revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Listo amigo ya agregue el codigo.

Comment: En vez de editar tu código para añadir la solución que te dieron, déjalo como estaba y acepta la respuesta ya que te ha ayudado a resolver tu problema, así otras personas pueden beneficiarse de la información que te han dado...

Answer (score 2):

La clase dentro del css se escribe `.jumbotron` con el punto por delante. No es una etiqueta propia de HTML, es una clase de Bootstrap, por eso debe anteponerse el punto `.` como indicador.

```css
body {
    background-image:   url('https://img.freepik.com/foto-gratis/textura-fondo_1404-93.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg') !important;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-color: #07121e!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Easter Eggs</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>   
        <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Este botón despliega la barra de navegación</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Easter Eggs</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Entradas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Favoritos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Autores</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <u1 class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Iniciar sesion</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Registro</a></li>
                    </u1>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>Easter Eggs</h1>
                <p>
                    Web dedicada a descubrir y compartir los Easter Eggs de los Videojuegos
                </p>
            </div>        
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Busqueda
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Que buscas?">
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="form-control">Buscar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" aria-hidden="true"></span> Filtro
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> Archivo
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ultimas entradas
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Todavia no hay entradas que mostrar</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listo encontré la solución, solo tuve que agregar una linea de código en el `<head>`, le agregue `<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" />` y listo me los cargo el netbeans, en el `href="`coloquen la ruta de sonde se encuentran sus estilos`"` en vez de esto `css/estilos.css` ya que es la ruta donde yo tenia los estilos.

Comment: Si ya estás usando los estilos de Bootstrap, no me parece una buena práctica (ni lógico) crear otra hoja de estilos cuyo contenido sean las mismas clases de Bootstrap y les apliques `!important`.

Comment: Entonces cual seria la manera correcta de darle estilo a una pagina web? Y lo de '!important' si no lo agrego no aplica los estilos.

Comment: No es que sea incorrecta, pues a fin de cuentas te funciona como lo estás haciendo. Puedes usar las hojas de estilo que desees en tu proyecto, el problema es cuando creas redundancia entre ellas y quieres solucionarlo aplicando la regla `!important`. Por ejemplo, Bootstrap tiene la clase `jumbotron` dentro de su librería, con unos atributos que ya están definidos. Cuál es el objetivo entonces de crear otra hoja de estilos en la que estás forzando los mismas propiedades que ya trae Bootstrap? Aconsejo visites: https://librosweb.es/libro/css/capitulo-13/recomendaciones-generales-sobre-css.html